# How do I reconvert JSON into custom object using TypeToken?

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

Basically, I have an object of the type:

```
ArrayList<Events>
```

Which I converted into JSON using gson to save it in my SharedPreferences. Now when I wanted to reconvert the JSON formatted data into my custom object structure, the application just stops responding (debugger says "application is running", no response after). This is the line:

```
Type eventType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Events>>() {}.getType();
events = gson.fromJson(eventString,eventType);
```

Comment: The code itself looks correct, but how large is the JSON input that you are converting? The conversion may well take time if there are many events and depending on the size/complexity of the "Events" object graph.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul It's only maybe 50 or so Events, it should definitely not take that long at all. Also, when I used a generic ArrayList.class as the Type specifier, it will finish the conversion near instantly.

Comment: What does the `Events` class look like, and what does the String you're parsing look like? Is it well formatted JSON? Have you mapped (created classes for) the entire hierarchy that `Events` contains? If you disconnect the debugger and let it run, does it result in an Exception?